# Truncate name but not year in authoryear-comp style citations

Tags: biblatex, citing

When passing two cite keys of the same author to the citation command in the `author year-comp` style of biblatex, the name is only printed once. That is:

```
Author 2001, Author 2011 =>  Author 2001, 2011
```

In addition, if the two publications also share the same year, the year is also dropped and only the “unique labels” remain.

```
Author 2001a, Author 2001b => Author 2001a,b
```

Is there a way to get the first truncation without the second one? Like this:

```
Author 2001a, Author 2001b => Author 2001a, 2001b
```

I do not particularly like that, but it is required by a publisher.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Bib.bib}
    @book{One,
        title={Great Book},
        author={Author, Jane},
        year = {2001}
    }
    @book{Two,
        title={Another Great Book},
        author={Author, Jane},
        year = {2001}
    } 
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Bib}

\begin{document}

    \textcite{One,Two}
    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: See also [Multiple citations same author same year using biblatex---list year](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309697/35864) - I note that I used almost the same wording in the answer there, even though I wrote the answer below before I found the other one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be as easy as making `biblatex` "forget" about the last year with

```
\makeatletter
\AtEveryCitekey{\global\undef\cbx@lastyear}
\makeatother
```